# Primeng Calendar validation issue

Tags: validation, primeng, p-calendar

using primeng components for years now, but still have one validation problem with the calendar. Here is my calendar :

```
   <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="model.myDate"
              dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
              id="myDate"
              name="myDate"
              showIcon="true"
              appendTo="body"
              [disabled]="!isNew"
              required>
   </p-calendar>
```

Validation is working in two cases : if no date are entered (manually or by the datepicker), you can't validate the form (it is required). Also, if you pick a date with the tool and then manually delete it from the input, the input turns red and also, form is not validated.

BUT, in the first case, (so field is empty) there are no "red bar" like all the other primeng components. So the user has no way to know that this field is required or in error.

All other components (dropdown, textfield, etc) have that "red bar" in front of the component telling the user it is invalid, but not the calendar. Is there any workaround ?

I did try manually do some css to force it, but could not achieve it.
Thanks in advance.